# Как сделать генератор уникальных чисел?

Tags: java, случайные-числа, arraylist

Здравствуйте. У меня есть

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
Random r = new Random();

for (int i =  0; i < 10; i++){
    myArray.add(r.nextInt(10) + 1);
}
```

Но он заполняет `ArrayList` любыми числами, а мне надо, чтобы он делал каждое число уникальным (без повторений), и в случайном порядке их раскидывал. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: [тасование Фишера–Йетса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать проще то, что вы хотите, познакомьтесь с этим: [Множества: Set, HashSet, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/set.php).

На вашем примере:

```
Random random = new Random();
Set<Integer> numberSet = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numberSet.add(random.nextInt(10) + 1);
}
```

Повторяющихся элементов не будет.

Comment: Но весь смысл случайных чисел исчезает, если так сделать, то все числа будут идти по порядку 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: Все я понял, я использовал LinkedHashSet вместо Hashset и все получилось, спасибо вам !

Comment: @НечаевИлья нет, вы совсем не поняли. Подумайте чуть подольше: вы заполняете массив длиной в 10 элементов, БЕЗ ПОВТОРЕНИЙ, значениями в диапазоне от 0 до 10. Естественно, они могут и по порядку пойти. У вас будут значения только 1, 2, 3... и в каком порядке - как повезет. Поставьте диапазон побольше и LinkedHashSet не понадобится.

Comment: мне как-раз таки нужно только 10 элементов, и когда я делал с помощью hashset, то из 10 раз мне 10 раз выпадали числа в порядке возрастания, а они мне желательно в случайном порядке, скорее всего это из-за моего не правильно поставленного вопроса вы не поняли меня, прошу прощения )

Comment: @НечаевИлья я постарался ответить на вопрос, сформулированный вами :) Если вы подразумевали что-то другое, можете дополнить свой вопрос. А также использовать ответ, данный ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Тогда нужно random permutation, 
[Случайные перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Если по простому, то берем первый элемент и меняем местами с любым другим, потом берем второй и меняем местами с любым кроме первого и так до конца

Само собой сначала нужно заполнить массив значениями, например

```
myArray.add(i)
```

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. Человек сказал о том, что при рандомном заполнении элементы могут повторяться, и что он этого не хочет.

Comment: нет я понял и объяснил как это сделать

Comment: Вчитайтесь заново и внимательнее.

Comment: даже не глядя в профиль понятно, что МГУ

Comment: Спасибо и вам, что не прошли мимо и попытались помочь ! )

Comment: @PavelGridin даже открыв мой профиль, вы не смогли внимательно прочитать. Что тут еще добавить? Я учусь не в МГУ, а в другом Университете, но тоже Московском Государственном. Стоило лишь прочитать больше одной строки.

Comment: ok, погорячился